# COD ou COI dans la construction "faire + infinitif"

Tags: grammaire, constructions

Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer pourquoi est-ce qu'on dit :

> a) Qu'est-ce qui **l**'a fait réagir comme ça ?

mais

> b) Qu'est-ce qui **lui** a fait dire ça ?

Donc, pourquoi emploie-t-on un COD dans la première phrase, mais un COI dans la deuxième ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est tout simple : « faire réagir qqu » est la construction du premier verbe qui appelle donc un COD parce qu'il n'y a pas de préposition et « faire dire **à** qqu » est la construction du second dans lequel la préposition « à » indique un COI ou un complément d'attribution  dans d'autres formes (Ils les ont fait le lui donner.); ce mécanisme fonctionne sans exception.

Answer (score 1):

Par ce qu'on :

Fait réagir quelqu'un (quelqu'un COD de *réagir*)

Mais que l'on

Fait dire **à** quelqu'un (quelqu'un COI de *dire*)